# vuejs - v-bind em pseudo elemento css

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Estou precisando alterar a cor de um pseudo elemento, de acordo com algumas condições. Para simplificar, fiz primeiro sem nenhuma condição, apenas quero mudar a cor através do v-bind

Tenho um pseudo elemento CSS:

```css
.status span:before {
    content: '';
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 4px solid #3e70ff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    left: 42%;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}
```

No HTML estou fazendo assim:

```html
div v-bind:class="'span:before'" v-bind:style="{ color: 'red' }"></div>
```

Porém, não consegui mudar a cor do pseudo elemento. Como posso fazer?

Comment: Não entendo de Vue, mas parto da premissa de que pseudo-elementos só são alteráveis no próprio CSS. Isso porque eles não existem no DOM, por isso são _pseudo-elementos_.

Answer (score 2):

Não faz sentido você querer modificar o CSS com Vue.

Faz mais sentido você deixar seu CSS preparado para a mudança e fazer com que o Vue mude o "estado" de seu componente.

Exemplo:

Vamos dizer que você queira que o `span:before` tenha a fonte vermelha quando um botão for clicado.

Você deve criar um CSS com o valor padrão do `span:before` e outro com as alterações de estado do elemento. Veja um exemplo:

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: () => ({
        ativo: false
    })
})
```

```css
span:before {
    content: "[before] ";
}

span.ativo:before {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span :class="{ativo}">Meu span</span>
  <br>
  <button @click="ativo = !ativo">Botão</button>
</div>
```